# Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Let $p$ belong to $X$. What can you mention about the connectivity of $X$, if $\{p\}$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Let $p$ belong to $X$. What can you mention about the connectivity of $X$, if $\{p\}$ is open?

Comment: Note $X\setminus\{p\}$ is always open (prove it)

Answer (score 2):

If $X = \{p\}$ then $X$ is connected.

If $X \neq \{p\}$ then $X$ is not connected. This follows from the fact that in a metric space singletons are closed, together with the fact that in a connected space the only sets that are both open and closed are the empty set and the set itself.

Comment: What if the metric space (X,d) has more than one point? What can you mention about the connectivity of X?

Comment: @h.tutar: that's covered in the second part of my answer... If $X$ has more than one point the it is different from $\{p\}$...

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote? I'd be glad to improve my answer where needed..